# Flash mobile memory allocation issue (iOS)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, memory-leaks, actionscript, air

We are programming an application, which have to parse a huge JSON data, during which application allocates a huge amount reserve memory (pic1 pic2).

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

During profiling via Adobe Scout we have noticed some strange behavior.

The system(IOS Iphone5s) allocates reserve memory (the silver part of figure) which is not used.

Why the system allocates so huge amount of reserve memory and how to prevent that???

Comment: The ones who could possibly answer the **why** question are those responsible for the parser itself. The second part, well... 1) Split the data into smaller chunks. 2) **System.gc()** immediately after the parsing to free the unused memory.

Comment: Have you tried using bloodycrypto's json paser? It seriously must be whatever parser you're using or something you did to cause a memory leak before or after you parsed the object.

Comment: @Organis I've tried to do that. But the problem is that after calling garbage collector the reserved allocated memory doesn't decrease. 
As I've researched in flash system allocates reserve memory which is for not allocating memory every time when objects are created. 
In our case what is strange is that the (1) system doesn't decrease amount of reserved memory even if we decrease current used total memory ("delete" that objects and call System.gc()), and (2) also after that the system will not use that reserved memory (see the picture) instead it reserving additional memory.

Comment: Maybe it's not the same case, but this helped me years ago (on Android though), I had >30mb JSON strings to parse.
http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2260

Comment: @gMirian It helps a lot due to parse time and memory performance but the problem still remains with iOS. 
Thank you